# Set default value for traefik.docker.network

Tags: docker, traefik

Is it possible to set a default value for `traefik.docker.network` instead of specifying it for every container that needs to be exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new [feature request](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3449) in traefik issue tracker and they have hence added this feature.

It is now possible to specify the default network as `network: <default network name>` under the `[docker]` section of the configuration file.